# How to deploy Content generated in a Target to AppX package in a UWP app with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, uwp, appx

I have a C# XAML UWP project created in Visual Studio 2017 and I have some assets that I want to convert and have deployed to the AppX package. However, I am unable to get my converted assets deployed without directly adding them to the AppXPackagePayload.

I have created a simplified test case with a vanilla C# XAML App and a couple text files in a *RawData* folder. I want the text files converted (copied for now) and deployed to the *Data* folder in my AppX.

I added the following to my csproj right before the import of the Xaml.CSharp.targets (I added the ConvertedData item type just for debugging):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <RawData Include="RawData\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="ConvertData" BeforeTargets="Compile" Inputs="@(RawData)" Outputs="Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ConvertedData Include="Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)" />
    <Content Include="Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Creating Data: @(RawData) -> Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="%(RawData.Identity)" DestinationFiles="Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)" />
</Target>
<Target Name="DisplayContent" AfterTargets="ConvertData" BeforeTargets="Compile">
  <Message Importance="high" Text="RawData: @(RawData)" />
  <Message Importance="high" Text="ConvertedData: @(ConvertedData)" />
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Content: @(Content)" />
</Target>
```

The log output when building is this:

```
1>  Creating Data: RawData\Hello.txt -> Data\Hello.txt
1>  Creating Data: RawData\World.txt -> Data\World.txt
1>  RawData: RawData\Hello.txt;RawData\World.txt
1>  ConvertedData: Data\Hello.txt;Data\World.txt
1>  Content: Properties\Default.rd.xml;Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png;Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png;Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png;Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png;Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png;Assets\StoreLogo.png;Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png;Data\Hello.txt;Data\World.txt
```

Which is as expected. I now have a *Data* folder in my project folder containing my "converted" text files. However, the files in the *Data* folder never make it to the *AppX* folder when the app is deployed even though they are listed as Content. All the other assets that were not generated in a Target do get deployed. It seems as if Content items created in a Target do not get added to the AppXPackagePayload.

If I add the following to the Target's ItemGroup:

```
<AppxPackagePayload Include="Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)">
  <TargetPath>Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)</TargetPath>
</AppxPackagePayload>
```

Then the items in the Data folder get deployed to the AppX. However, I feel that just adding my items to Content in the Target should be enough to get them deployed. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to reload the project ?

Comment: Yes many times! Actually in my test case I outlined above I'm directly editing the csproj file, so Visual Studio forces a solution reload every time I make an edit. I have also tried restarting VS.

Comment: Following on from Nico's comment, it's worth clarifying that if the code were in an external props file rather than directly in the csproj, you must close and reload the entire solution to see any changes in VS. Unloading and reloading the specific project in the solution is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing of Content items happens before compilation, so you should replace

`BeforeTargets="Compile"`

with

`BeforeTargets="AssignTargetPaths"`

That should do the trick.

Comment: Yep, that worked! In hindsight, I should have realized it was just running at the wrong time. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case it's useful to someone, I put my sample project on Github: [https://github.com/jccaulfield/MSBuildTest](https://github.com/jccaulfield/MSBuildTest)

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution now which avoids the Target-generated Content items, as well as the explicit AppXPackagePayload. This works because I have a one-to-one mapping between my *RawData* and *Data* files so I can put all Content items outside the Target. It doesn't answer why Target-generated Content items do not deploy (and I'd still like to know why that's the case if anyone knows), but it does solve my problem in a clean way, so could be useful to others:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <RawData Include="RawData\**\*.*">
      <Visible>True</Visible>
    </RawData>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="@(RawData-> 'Data\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')">
      <Visible>True</Visible>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="ConvertData" BeforeTargets="Compile" Inputs="@(RawData)" Outputs="Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)">
  <Copy SourceFiles="%(RawData.Identity)" DestinationFiles="Data\%(RawData.RecursiveDir)%(RawData.Filename)%(RawData.Extension)" />
</Target>
```

Now my *Data* files are created in my project folder, and correctly deployed to the AppX folder.

Comment: This answer is really just a workaround which avoids the issue and might be helpful to others with a similar problem. I'm still hoping someone might be able to help with the underlying problem, i.e., why do my Content items emitted from a Target not get deployed.